# Add and edit Oracle Spatial Layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, editing, oracle-spatial

When I connect oracle layer are not enabled me all editing options. I can create and delete but not update.

[image: QGIS Node Tool Disabled]

It is an issue of users? permissions or privileges? metadata?

All works OK in AutoCADMap3D with the same credentials.

I'm working on Oracle Spatial 11g and QGIS 2.12

Answer (score 3):

We did have similar issue with Oracle Spatial. In our case we need to adding more permissios for geom-columns (or whatever column you use to store geometries).

```
GRANT UPDATE ("GEOM") ON "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE" TO "OTHERSCHEMA_USER";
```

It seems that other GIS desktop applications are not so strict.

More information from [QGIS Developer email list](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Problem-editing-geometries-with-no-owner-user-in-Oracle-spatial-11g-via-QGIS-td5272138.html).